# What is the typescript compiler's default lib value?

Tags: typescript, tsc

The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) says `--lib` is derived from `--target` by default:

> Note: If --lib is not specified a default list of libraries are
> injected. The default libraries injected are:
>
> - For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
> - For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost

The same documentation says that the default `--target` value is **ES3**:

> Specify ECMAScript target version:
>
> - "ES3" (default)
> - "ES5"
> - "ES6"/"ES2015"
> - "ES2016"
> - "ES2017"
> - "ES2018"
> - "ES2019"
> - "ES2020"
> - "ESNext"

So... what is `--lib` default value when neither `--lib` nor `--target` is set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the source code there is a [list of supported libs](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/663b19fe4a7c4d4ddaa61aedadd28da06acd27b6/src/lib/libs.json#L56-L64), which has a section called "Default libraries":

```
        // Default libraries
        "es5.full",
        "es2015.full",
        "es2016.full",
        "es2017.full",
        "es2018.full",
        "es2019.full",
        "es2020.full",
        "es2021.full",
        "esnext.full"
```

These correspond to your target setting.

Looking at the source code of one of these ([lib.es2017.full.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/663b19fe4a7c4d4ddaa61aedadd28da06acd27b6/lib/lib.es2017.full.d.ts)), you can see what it imports:

```
/// <reference lib="es2017" />
/// <reference lib="dom" />
/// <reference lib="webworker.importscripts" />
/// <reference lib="scripthost" />
/// <reference lib="dom.iterable" />
```

And FYI, all language levels import the previous. So for example: es2018 imports es2017, which imports es2016, which imports es2015, which imports es5. "es6" is unique because nothing imports it.

There appears to be no "es3" lib file in the source code, so I don't have an answer for that. Try setting `noLib`, see what breaks, and comment below.