# tsconfig.json target is not respected in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I changed the target in tsconfig from es5 to es2022 and restarted VS Code multiple times, but Intellisense is still importing from es5. TS version is selected as use workspace's version (5.2.2). When I try to use `new Error("", {cause: ""})` it doesn't recognize the `cause`. When I click `Go to Type Definition` it brings up the es5 version of the type. Am I doing something wrong? I have a monorepo setup with child configs inherit the base.

tsconfig.base.json

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom", "ES2021.String", "ESNext.String"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {},
  "exclude": ["tmp"]
}
```

tsconfig.json (this is an example for my next js project)

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [],
  "extends": "../../../../tsconfig.base.json"
}
```

index.ts

```
throw new Error("test", {
  cause: "hi"
}); // Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2. Go to Type Definition brings up lib.es5.d.ts
```

Comment: Use `es2022` in your `lib` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) does set the corresponding default for [`lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) (see also [What is the typescript compiler's default lib value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63943629/11107541)), but I guess if you specify `lib` manually, there's no merging with that corresponding default, so you need to specify the corresponding `lib` manually. Ex.

```json
"target": "es2022",
"lib": ["es2022", "dom", ...],
```